# In C++ can we dereference this pointer? If so then how and if not then why?

Tags: c++, gcc

I was working on a personal project with classes and didn't wanted to initialling each of the data members. So I made a call to `*((Classname *)(this)) = {};` in the constructor. Hoping that it would behave the way

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test1
{
    int data1;
    int data2;

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << data1 << ' ' << data2 << std::endl;
    }
};


class Test2
{
    int data1;
    int data2;

    public:
    Test()
    {
        *(Test *)(this) = {};
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << data1 << ' ' << data2 << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test1 t1;

    t1 = {}; /* I wanted the *((Classname *)(this)) = {}; to behave this way 
              * i.e. being able to initialise members with a initialisation list*/


    t1.print();

    Test2 t2;

    t2.print();

    return 0;
}
```

This while not generating any compilation errors ended up in a segmentation fault when creating class Test2 object.
Is there something that another way of initialising all the data-members to 0 or is there a restrictions that we cannot use `this` with initialisation lists? If so why? Or is this another one of undefined behaviours that I somehow stumbled upon? 
[If it something compiler dependent, I am using gcc compiler (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04))]

Comment: Please explain what you think `*(Test *)(this) = {};` should do. Its not quite clear how that is supposed to initialize members. What is the expected output?

Comment: FYI: Since C++11 you'd remove that constructor and simply declare the members with default initializers, e.g.: `int data1 = 0;`

Comment: Your constructor causes an _infinite recursion_ since it calls itself: [live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eLDkriH0jshDI4jZ). That `{}` creates a temporary of type `Test` initialized by default constructor, which runs `={}`, which...

Comment: note that this is a mild form of the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your question is about something you think is the solution to something else, but it isnt. You better ask about the actual problem you want to solve: How to initialize all members. `this` can be dereferenced, that isnt the problem in your code

Comment: @tadman I suppose OP does want to initialize them, but is too lazy to type the initializers, but yes could be more clear in the question

Comment: @idclev463035818 Sounds like the real question is "What's an easy way to use default values?"

Comment: is your actual question: "How to zero initialize all members of a class?" ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 thanks for the advice, I will keep that in mind. My question was regarding why was my code behaving the way it did.

Comment: I think @DanielLangr comment pretty much explains the situation.

Comment: ok, then you get the answer you were looking for, but you should really reconsider your initial approach to initialize the members

Comment: @idclev463035818 already on it sir :) (using a better way of initialising variables)

Comment: sorry, I did not want to suggest to change this question to ask soemthing else. It isnt nice to modify the question substantially once you got answers. The answer is now out of sync. If you have a different question, better open a new question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:** *I just realized you modified the code, and the new one does not make sense now. My answer is related to the original code.*

Yes, you can dereference `this` and invoke member functions on it, such as `this->f();` which is the same `(*this).f()`. Similarly, `(*this) = ...` is the same as `this->operator=(...);`.

The problem is that `(*this) = {};` causes that `{}` creating a temporary of type `Test` initialized by default constructor. Consequently, you **call the default constructor inside the default constructor**, which causes a recursion that is never ended in your case.

---

If you want to initialize members to zero *by default* (that is, if not specified otherwise in *constructor member initializer list*), simply use (since C++11):

```
int data1 = 0;
int data2 = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks!! this resolves why I was getting the error and how to go initialising data-members.

Comment: @NiteshMeena You're welcome and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, if you are ok with this answer, don't forget to _accept it_ to let others know that this issue is closed.